# To create an array programmatically

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

I want to create an array programmatically, like below using Kotlin. I don't know much about Java, Kotlin, and Android. Is this possible?

```kotlin
val list1 = mutableListOf<String>()
//  val array1 = arrayOf<String>()

for (i in 0 until 6) {
    list1.add(i, "\"$i\"")
}

println(list1)
```

Output: `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`

Can I convert a mutable List or ArrayList, to create a string array like, `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`?

This is for creating an array for AlertDialog.

```
     val m = item_type
     var n = m - 1
     var item_max = 0

     when(TextView.text) {
        "Title 1" -> {  
            item_type_from_list = item_type_list[n]
         }
     }

     val itemTypes = generateArray(1, item_type_from_list) // Function to      
      //  create desired array

    /*val itemTypes = arrayOf<String>(
     "1",
     "2",
     "3",
     "4",
     "5"
      */

     val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())

     mBuilder.setTitle("${TextView.text}")

     mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(itemTypes, selectedItems1[0]) { dialog, i     
     -> 
     selectedItems1[0] = i
     var item_type_selected = selectedItems1[0]
     dialog.dismiss()
     }

     val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
     mDialog.show()
```

You can also suggest any alternatives that I can do?

Comment: Would [toTyedArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) work?

Comment: val list3 = list1.toTypedArray()
for(element in list3){
    println(element)
}  Output is just - val list3: Array<String> - Scratches output, Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val list1 : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

And then you can add your elements like this:

```
for (i in 0 until 6) {
  list1.add(i.toString())
}
```

And for your AlertDialog, you can use the following:

```
mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(list1.toTypedArray(), selectedItems1[0]) { dialog, i -> 
         selectedItems1[0] = i
         var item_type_selected = selectedItems1[0]
         dialog.dismiss()
     }

val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
mDialog.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: But this is ArrayList. Can I convert this to an Array?

Comment: you cannot dynamically add elements to an Array. An array is fixed sized. why do you insist on having an array and not an arrayList? any specific reason?

Comment: This is for creating a list of options in AlertDialog. It says to give an Array as parameter. setSingleChoiceItems type. Is there an alternative that I can do?

Comment: You mean giving a list of options in a spinner? it will be very helpful if you add the code you have related to the AlertDialog to your question.

Comment: Just updated my answer and it is checked in Android Studio. it works.

Comment: Your suggestion removed the error, but no number list is seen in the dialog. It is blank. When I had used .toTypedArray in Scratches, Android Studio also, no array was in the output.

Comment: You are making a mistake in your implementation of my answer. i just added a screenshot of the result. it works as you can see. Maybe you are not populating the array correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
val list1= mutableListOf<String>()
```

`val array:Array<String> = list1.toTypedArray()`

Now, the result of printing elements of them would be the same but, `list1` is a `List` but `array` is an `Array`

Comment: Option1:

val list3 = list1.toTypedArray() 
for(element in list3){ println(element) }
Output is just - val list3: Array<String> (Scratches output, Android Studio)
It is not showing the array.

Option 2:

Unresolved reference: toArray  I'm not getting the desired output, i.e., when I used MutableList.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate an array:

```
val array = Array(6) { "$it" }
```

That creates an array with 6 elements, the lambda is the initialisation function that gets the index of the current element passed in. So I'm just turning that into a string here. Or you can use a function reference if you like, might be clearer:

```
val array = Array(6, Int::toString)
```

To convert a list into an array, use the `toTypedArray` function. You can create lists in the same way as above, btw:

```
// or MutableList
val list = List(6) { "$it" }
val array = list.toTypedArray()
```

or as a more general case (not the best idea here, but it's how you can generate arbitrary collections with a chain of transformations):

```
val nums = (0..5).map { "$it" }.toTypedArray()
```

Also, just in case you're not aware, there are special array types to represent arrays of primitives:

```
val integers = Array(6) { it }
val ints = IntArray(6) { it }
```

The first creates an `Integer[]` array type under the hood, which is an array of `Integer` objects. The second creates an `int[]` which is an array of `int` primitives, and is much more efficient. Just something to be aware of in case it's important!